# Magento 2 Rest Get Orders C#

Tags: magento2, orders, rest-api

I am using C # to search for orders from last month (last 30 days). Magento version 2 using REST, I am using the call as follows:

http://magentoserver/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=2017-08-01&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gt

The remote server returned an error: `(401) Unauthorized.`

If the call is:

http://magentoserver/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria=

The server returns all orders.

It's not an authorization error, I really don't find the right way to build the search criteria. I don't find any documentation that explains how to do it

Comment: Welcome to Magento StackExchange! could you specify what version of Magento is this question about?

Comment: Magento version 2.0.13

Answer (score 0):

I'm building the code like this:

```
    public class ApiClient
{

    public ApiClient(string magentoServer, string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, string accessToken, string accessTokenSeccret)
    {
        MagentoServer = magentoServer;
        ConsumerKey = consumerKey;
        ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret;
        AccessToken = accessToken;
        AccessTokenSecret = accessTokenSeccret;
    }

    #region Request

    public HttpWebRequest CreateAuthorizedRequest(string url, string requestMethod, string filter)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        if (filter == null)
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        else
            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url + "?" + filter.ToString());

        OAuthBase oAuth = new OAuthBase();
        string nonce = oAuth.GenerateNonce();
        string timeStamp = oAuth.GenerateTimeStamp();
        string parameters;
        string normalizedUrl;
        string signature = oAuth.GenerateSignature(new Uri(url), ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret,
        AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret, requestMethod, timeStamp, nonce, OAuthBase.SignatureTypes.HMACSHA1,
        out normalizedUrl, out parameters);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("OAuth ");
        sb.AppendFormat("oauth_token=\"{0}\",", AccessToken);
        sb.AppendFormat("oauth_version=\"{0}\",", "1.0");
        sb.AppendFormat("oauth_signature_method=\"{0}\",", "HMAC-SHA1");
        sb.AppendFormat("oauth_nonce=\"{0}\",", nonce);
        sb.AppendFormat("oauth_timestamp=\"{0}\",", timeStamp);
        sb.AppendFormat("oauth_consumer_key=\"{0}\",", ConsumerKey);
        sb.AppendFormat("oauth_signature=\"{0}\"", signature);

        request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = sb.ToString();
        request.Method = requestMethod;

        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.KeepAlive = true;

        return request;
    }

    public string FetchRequest(HttpWebRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            string responseText = string.Empty;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        responseText = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                        return responseText;
                    }
                }
            }

            return responseText;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
    }






    public static string GetValues(string _call, string method)
    {
        ApiClient client = new ApiClient(MagentoServer, ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, AccessToken, AccessTokenSecret);
        string url = url_base + _call;
        string t = null;
        HttpWebRequest myReq = client.CreateAuthorizedRequest(url, method, null);
        t = client.FetchRequest(myReq);
        if (t != null)
            t = t.Replace("\\/", "/");
        return t;
    }
```

The call it's made like:

```
        public string url = "http://" + magentoServer;
        public string url_base = "/index.php/rest/V1/";


        string _call = "orders?";
        _call += "searchCriteria[currentPage]=1&";
        _call += "searchCriteria[pageSize]=1";
        string _resp = Magento2Form.GetValues(_call, "GET", null);
```

This single call only with pageSize and currentPage gives me the answer:

```
Error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```